# IOException being swallowed when input socket is unexpectedly closed

Tags: java, sockets, codenameone, socketexception

This snippet is failing when the socket is unexpectedly closed.  No
`IOException` is thrown, and `s.read()` never returns.

```
  try {
   while (!doneReading)
   {    /* read blocks waiting for data */
    int readResult = s.read(inBuf, inBufLength, 1);
    ...
   }
  }
  catch (IOException err) { .. }
```

When the socket is initially closed, the stack is as follows:

```
    Thread [Thread-10] (Suspended (exception SocketException))  
        SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]    
        SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) line: 150 
        SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 121  
        SocketInputStream.read(byte[]) line: 107    
        JavaSEPort$SocketImpl.readFromStream() line: 7462   
        JavaSEPort.readFromSocketStream(Object) line: 7601  
        Socket$SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 179   
        NetConn.runRead() line: 1044    
        NetConn.run() line: 989 
        Thread.run() line: 744  
C:\java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javaw.exe (Dec 23, 2015, 4:47:53 PM)
```

the socketexception  is apparently caught, and rethrown as an ioexception
at this point:

```
    Thread [Thread-10] (Suspended (exception IOException))  
        owns: DualStackPlainSocketImpl  (id=93) 
        DualStackPlainSocketImpl(AbstractPlainSocketImpl).available() line: 465 [local variables unavailable]   
        SocketInputStream.available() line: 238 
        JavaSEPort$SocketImpl.getAvailableInput() line: 7428    
        JavaSEPort$SocketImpl.readFromStream() line: 7452   
        JavaSEPort.readFromSocketStream(Object) line: 7601  
        Socket$SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 179   
        NetConn.runRead() line: 1044    
        NetConn.run() line: 989 
        Thread.run() line: 744  

        NetConn.run() line: 989 
        Thread.run() line: 744
```

It's hard to tell more about what's going on because the source for JavaSEPort is not bound 
in the eclipse environment

More info:  I acquired more sources, and can see that JavaSEPort.readFromStream catches the IOException and returns null. A few levels higher, in Socket.read there is a while (buffer==null) that will never be escaped.  This completely explains the behavior - I see an endless loop of stack traces and read never returns.

Comment: Define 'socket is unexpectedly closed'. Do you mean you close it yourself? And are you checking the result of `read()` for -1?

Comment: closed by the server end. the client isn't expecting it.

Comment: That's a closure of the *connection,* not the socket: the socket remains open until you close it; and the peer closure shows up as `read()` returning -1, which you haven't answered my question about.

Comment: Yes, I check for read returning -1, but in this case read never returns, and the underlying socket code is stuck in an infinite loop.  DId you notice this is tagged "codenameone".  This isn't the usual sockets implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When there is an error you should get the `connectionError` callback instead of an exception.

Comment: The connection was established and running for a while.  I wouldn't expect to get a connection error callback at this time.  Having looked over the code I'm pretty sure I'm not, but I'll confirm that tomorrow.

Comment: I confirmed that I never get a connection error callback.

Comment: The stack you posted lacks packages, isn't `NetConn` your class? If so can't you catch the exception?

Comment: I do catch the IOException, but it is caught and not rethrown by getAvailableInput, so NetConn never sees it.  It might require some careful thought to propagate the IOException only when there is no unseen data available.

Comment: Can you file an issue on that? FYI there is a cn1lib that has socket support as well and might be more convenient for your use case: https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

Comment: Where does one file an issue?